# Load ngmin in r.js build file fails

Tags: node.js, angularjs, requirejs, npm

I'm trying to use `ngmin` in `requirejs`'s `r.js` following [this](http://merrickchristensen.com/articles/build-angular-with-requirejs.html), but for some reason I am unable to get it to work. I've installed `ngmin` and `requirejs` through `npm` both globally and locally and neither of these options load `ngmin` properly in `onBuildRead()`. I've also exported `NODE_PATH`, but this didn't help either.

The build file works without providing the hook function which isolates the problem, but I'm not a `nodejs` expert, so I don't know how to troubleshoot this any further. Any help is appreciated.

```
({
    mainConfigFile: './static/js/boot.js',
    baseUrl: './static/js',
    name: 'boot',
    include: 'require.js',
    out: './static/js/main-built.js',
    normalizeDirDefines: 'all',
    onBuildRead: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
        var ngmin = require('ngmin');
        console.log(ngmin);  // ngmin is undefined
        return ngmin.annotate(contents); // no method annotate of undefined
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you are trying to call nodejs's require inside r.js's build config file. But this file is just a configuration - it is not executed by node - it is only read by r.js optimizer. You may wrap your build config into Grunt task in following way:

1. Put this file into your project's root

   **Gruntfile.js**

   ```
   module.exports = function(grunt) {
      'use strict';
       // Project configuration.
       var config = {

          requirejs : {
             compile : {
                options : {
                   mainConfigFile: './static/js/boot.js',
                   baseUrl: './static/js',
                   name: 'boot',
                   include: 'require.js',
                   out: './static/js/main-built.js',
                   normalizeDirDefines: 'all',
                   onBuildRead: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
                       var ngmin = require('ngmin');
                       console.log(ngmin);
                       return ngmin.annotate(contents);
                   }
                }
              }
           }
       };

       grunt.initConfig(config);

       // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
       grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');

       grunt.registerTask('build', ['requirejs:compile']);

       // Default task.
       grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

   };
   ```
2. Install grunt-cli globally via npm

   `npm install -g grunt-cli`
3. Install required modules into your project

   `npm install grunt grunt-contrib-requirejs`
4. Run default grunt task:

   `grunt`

This will requirejs task. Since Grungfile.js is normal CommonJs module you may easy use any npm modules in it. More about Grunt [here](http://gruntjs.com/).

After learning more about grunt, see [this plugin](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin) - I think it may be useful in current context, if you will decide to use grunt.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid the installation of grunt (yet another library), but if that's the only possibility, I'll try it out and let you know how I go...